# Using gcc to compile a c++ program for linux linking static and dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to compile a program using a makefile and gcc as compiler.

I must link my program with static and dynamic libraries. I've linked the static libraries as follows:the name of my static libraries are libverifp.a and libtls_64.a, then I wrote -lverifp and -ltls_64.

Besides, I must link a dynamic library named libverifp.so and I do not know how link it.

The error message that appears is:

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libtls_64.so, needed by /mnt/f/code/ext/verifp_1.40/bin/linux/x64/libverifp.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

I understand I must link libverifp.so but I do not know how can I do.

Comment: So, do you have a `libtls_64.so`? Also, why do you _need_ to link the dynamic `libverifp.so` if you also have a static `libverifp.a`?

Comment: Have you set the library paths properly? Please show a [mcve] - mainly the folder structure and build&linker commands.

Comment: Anyway, the error message is that the library loader cannot find your lib in the dedicated folder it's looking for. A good way to handle the issue is to add the path to your lib into the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. You can also move your library into one of the folders that are searched by the library loader or also set the `rpath` in the compilation so that the path will be embedded into the executable.

Comment: 1 Question (@user17732522): When I compile with 'make' this is the error message:
"/usr/bin/ld: warning: libtls_64.so, needed by /mnt/f/code/ext/verifp_1.40/bin/linux/x64/libverifp.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)"
then I understand I need to link with libverifp.so.

2 an 3 Question (@Quimby @Fareanor): I added the path where are all these libraries in gcc parameters: "-L/mnt/f/code/ext/verifp_1.40/bin/linux/x64" 

Thanks for your answers